Pyspark: Flattening of Hierarchy table dynamically
I have a pyspark dataframe like below:
HierarchyNode       ParentNode
 U1.1               U1
 U1.1.1             U1.1
 24.0.1             24
 24.1.1             24.0.1
 24.1.1.1           24.1.1

This is more of a hierarchy table. I want to flat this and the expected out put should be:
ParentWBSElementExternalID  LN-1            LN-2              LN-3
 U1                         NULL            NULL              NULL
 U1                         U1.1            NULL              NULL
 U1                         U1.1            U1.1.1            NULL
 24                         NULL            NULL              NULL
 24                         24.0.1          NULL              NULL
 24                         24.0.1          24.1.1            NULL
 24                         24.0.1          24.1.1        24.1.1.1

Using recursive CTE is one solution, but unfortunately in databricks we can't have recursive CTE. Also, as you can see that the level of HierarchyNode i.e. child node can go upto 2 level, 3 level etc. Hence it is dynamic.
I have followed this SO link. But not getting any proper answer.
Any help would be appreciated using PySpark.

Yes, you can do this using recursive CTE. You are also correct that there is no databricks SQL recursive CTE. But there is a pyspark equivalent as you see in this brilliant article.
I'm going to use that as a base to resolve your problem and will be using pyspark and SQL.
First store your dataframe into a temporary view.
df.createOrReplaceTempView('test1')

Now comes the recursive CTE bit by referring to the article mentioned above.
i = 1
df = spark.sql("""
        SELECT ParentNode,
        HierarchyNode,
        1 AS level
        FROM test1
        """)
# this view is our 'CTE' that we reference with each pass
df.createOrReplaceTempView('recursion_df')

print("entering loop")
while True:
    # select data for this recursion level
    new_df = spark.sql("""
        SELECT
            r.ParentNode,
            t.HierarchyNode,
            (level + 1) AS level
            FROM test1 t
            INNER JOIN recursion_df r
            ON r.HierarchyNode = t.ParentNode
        """)

    # this view is our 'CTE' that we reference with each pass
    new_df.createOrReplaceTempView('recursion_df')
    # add the results to the main output dataframe
    df = df.union(new_df)
    # if there are no results at this recursion level then break
    print(f"{i} : {new_df.count()}")
    if (new_df.count() == 0 or i == 5) :
        df.createOrReplaceTempView("final_df")
        break
    else:
        i += 1

Now create a temporary view off the result to get the root parent Nodes.
%sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW TEST1 AS
SELECT ParentNode FROM final_df WHERE level = 1 and ParentNode NOT IN (SELECT HierarchyNode FROM final_df);

Since you already know that the level cannot be greater than 3, you can create a union statement like so
%sql
SELECT c.ParentNode, r.HierarchyNode AS LN_1, NULL as LN_2, NULL as LN_3 FROM TEST1 c LEFT JOIN final_df r ON r.ParentNode = c.ParentNode AND r.level = 0
UNION
SELECT c.ParentNode, r.HierarchyNode AS LN_1, NULL as LN_2, NULL as LN_3 FROM TEST1 c LEFT JOIN final_df r ON r.ParentNode = c.ParentNode AND r.level = 1
UNION
SELECT c.ParentNode, r.HierarchyNode AS LN_1, s.HierarchyNode as LN_2, NULL as LN_3 FROM TEST1 c 
LEFT JOIN final_df r ON r.ParentNode = c.ParentNode AND r.level = 1
LEFT JOIN final_df s ON s.ParentNode = c.ParentNode AND s.level = 2 
UNION
SELECT c.ParentNode, r.HierarchyNode AS LN_1, s.HierarchyNode as LN_2, t.HierarchyNode as LN_3 FROM TEST1 c 
LEFT JOIN final_df r ON r.ParentNode = c.ParentNode AND r.level = 1
LEFT JOIN final_df s ON s.ParentNode = c.ParentNode AND s.level = 2
LEFT JOIN final_df t ON t.ParentNode = c.ParentNode AND t.level = 3 
; 

And your result is
UPDATE*
The above answer assumes that the level recursion is 3. However, let's say we do not know what the level is.
First execute the recursive CTE pyspark function. You need to cap the recursive lvl at some max. It can really be anything (say 100) as the loop will break when either there is no more elements or if the max recursion has been reached.
recursion_lvl = 5
i = 1
df = spark.sql("""
        SELECT ParentNode,
        HierarchyNode,
        1 AS level
        FROM test1
        """)
# this view is our 'CTE' that we reference with each pass
df.createOrReplaceTempView('recursion_df')

print("entering loop")
while True:
    # select data for this recursion level
    new_df = spark.sql("""
        SELECT
            r.ParentNode,
            t.HierarchyNode,
            (level + 1) AS level
            FROM test1 t
            INNER JOIN recursion_df r
            ON r.HierarchyNode = t.ParentNode
        """)

    # this view is our 'CTE' that we reference with each pass
    new_df.createOrReplaceTempView('recursion_df')
    # add the results to the main output dataframe
    df = df.union(new_df)
    # if there are no results at this recursion level then break
    print(f"{i} : {new_df.count()}")
    if (new_df.count() == 0 or i == recursion_lvl) :
        df.createOrReplaceTempView("final_df")
        break
    else:
        i += 1

Now fetch the unique base roots (as shown above)
%sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW TEST1 AS
SELECT ParentNode FROM final_df WHERE level = 1 and ParentNode NOT IN (SELECT HierarchyNode FROM final_df);

SELECT * FROM TEST1;

Now get the max level of recursion in your data
lvldf = spark.sql("SELECT MAX(level) AS MAXLVL from final_df;")
lvlmax = lvldf.head().asDict()['MAXLVL']
print(lvlmax)

Finally is the complicated piece of code which does the looping.
-Create an empty final table.
-Insert rows with the base parent root and nulls for remaining columns
-Loop and create insert statements and execute them on the final table.
   unionsql = "SELECT c.ParentNode,"
    col = ""
    for i in range(lvlmax):
        col = col + f"NULL AS LN_{i+1}"
        if (i+1) < lvlmax:
            col = col + ','
    unionsql = "SELECT c.ParentNode," + col + ' FROM TEST1 c LEFT JOIN final_df r ON r.ParentNode = c.ParentNode AND r.level = 0'
    
    print(unionsql)
    
    createsql = "CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE final_table (HierarchyNode STRING, "
    for i in range(lvlmax):
        createsql = createsql + f"LN_{i+1} STRING"
        if (i+1) < lvlmax:
            createsql = createsql + ", "
    createsql = createsql + ");"
    
    print(createsql)
    spark.sql(createsql)   # Execute the create table statement
    spark.sql("INSERT INTO final_table " + unionsql)  # INSERT THE ROOT parent with nulls for remaining cols
    
    #Check the max
    lvldf = spark.sql("SELECT MAX(level) AS MAXLVL from final_df;")
    lvlmax = lvldf.head().asDict()['MAXLVL']
    print(lvlmax)
    
    sql = "INSERT INTO final_table SELECT c.ParentNode, "
    jointmp = ""
    for i in range(lvlmax):
        for j in range(i+1):
            sql = sql + f" a{j+1}.HierarchyNode AS LN_{j+1}"
            if (j+1) < (lvlmax):
                sql = sql + ','
        for k in range(i+1, lvlmax):
            sql = sql + f" NULL as LN_{k+1}"
            if (k+1) < (lvlmax):
                sql = sql + ','
        jointmp = jointmp + f" LEFT JOIN final_df a{i+1} ON a{i+1}.ParentNode = c.ParentNode AND a{i+1}.level = {i+1}"
        sql = sql + f" FROM TEST1 c " + jointmp
        print(sql)
        spark.sql(sql)
        sql = "INSERT INTO final_table SELECT c.ParentNode, "

The final table will contain duplicates. So to get what you need just select distinct like so.
%sql
Select DISTINCT * FROM final_table;


Since you already know that the level cannot be greater than 3, you can create a union statement like so ---- This assumption is not correct. Lets assume we don't know the max_level.

Then keep the union in a loop pr form the final sql statement using a loop. Since you will know the max level from the level column from recurisve cte pyspark function. But you need set a cap of the recursion.A large number is also fine. In my example I set it 5.

@pythondumb You can refer to my updated answer to address your dynamic recursion level needs.

Thanks I already sorted that. However the bonus part is creating SQL string. Many thanks!

I am following your query but when I am running SELECT * FROM final_df I am not getting any results.

Not sure what's wrong. I'm attaching the link to my notebook for your reference. https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/5966603894607676/2313883698835693/7821383541163359/latest.html

I think issue is when you are creating TEST1 view. In the Select clause shouldn't it be and ParentNode IN (select distinct Heirachynode from final_df) ?

It should be NOT IN. Because we are looking for the Root ParentNode which is not present in Heirachynode column. Looking at your example, I'm referring to USREBT2 and 1004052024. Whether you use distinct or not, doesn't change the outcome.  If you import my notebook to your environment and run it, you should see the results.

How  to generate the UNION statement dynamically? I don't want to insert the records into a table, rather generate the SQL union all statement.

This should be a separate question

The INSERT INTO Statement is a bit confusing. For lvlmax=3 ideally there would be 2 union block. Therefore, we should expect 3 INSERT block. But the output from the generated dynamically has more than 2 INSERT block, when lvlmax=2.

The loop is defined as for i in range(lvlmax) which means for lvlmax = 2, the loop will be executed only twice (i=0 and 1). So only 2 INSERT statements. The 1st INSERT statement outside the loop is to INSERT the Parent nodes with NULLS in all columns. This is required for any value of lvlmax. There will be duplicates in the final table but these are removed when we do the final SELECT DISTINCT.

Ok thanks. At the last , I saw that query. I am trying to create the  UNION  part dynamically. But no luck so far. Meanwhile, can we enter into a chat?

You can refer to this notebook which generates the union sql statement dynamically. I didn't get time to test it out for all scenarios but it should be something you can start with https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/5966603894607676/3478623606181075/7821383541163359/latest.html

Sorry for late revert on this. I am still finding issues while running the code. Specifically, in the select * from final_df I am not getting any rows where level>1. Not even in your sample code.

Are you scrolling through all the rows displayed? Or do a SELECT * from final_df where level > 1; I've provided the full notebook with results attached. I've reverified the code and there is no problem there. I suggest you open a new question and show us what you are doing and what are the results. Continuing this on comments on a closed question is counter productive.
